# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, selinux, aosp

I am trying to copy the file from `/storage/emulated/0/test.txt` to `/cache/SH_DIR/` via android user application ,

getting error like below :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cache/SH_DIR/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

When I have created as system application like , Included Application code as past of AOSP then able to copy the file to `/cache/SH_DIR/` location.

May I need to add anything in the SEpolicy to copy file to /cacahe/SH_DIR/ from user application.

Can you please help me , Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you copy files - using an app (then please edit your question and provide app name and link to Play Store) or from a PC via USB/MTP?

Comment: I am trying copy file from application (pragmatically), and that application I have developed.

Comment: Sorry but this site is for Android users only. For app development questions please use https.//stackoverflow.com. When posting there include the relevant code parts of your app into the question so that the other developers can help you identifying the problem source.

Comment: Sure, Thank you

Comment: BNTW: Are you sure an app has write permissions to create a file in `/cache/SH_DIR/`? I have never seen an app using that directory. Even with adb I don't have access to `/cache`.

Comment: Question has been recreated on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67999464/java-io-filenotfoundexception-cache-test-test-txt-open-failed-eacces-permis